# Analytic solutions to a Stochastic Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I want to solve an SDE as follows:
$$
dX_t = \alpha(\beta - X_t)dt + dB_t,\quad X_0 = x_0
$$
where $\alpha$, $\beta$ are positive constants and B_t is a Browian motion independent to $X_t$.Is there a way to solve it? Thank in advance for any help or some references to this kind of equation.

Comment: The condition that $(B_t)$ is independent from $(X_t)$ is absurd.

Answer (score 1):

Let assume this
$$
Y_t = X_t\mathrm{e}^{\alpha t}
$$
then using Ito we find
$$
dY_t = \alpha  X_t\mathrm{e}^{\alpha t} dt + \mathrm{e}^{\alpha t}dX_t
$$
with some rearrangement we can find
$$
\mathrm{e}^{-\alpha t} dY_t = dX_t + \alpha X_t dt 
$$
which looks awfully like what you have as the original SDE above except we have 
$$
dX_t = \alpha\beta dt -\alpha X_t dt  + dB_t
$$
thus we can easily see
$$
\mathrm{e}^{-\alpha t} dY_t = \alpha\beta dt + dB_t
$$
thus
$$
dY_t = \alpha\beta \mathrm{e}^{\alpha t} dt + \mathrm{e}^{\alpha t}dB_t
$$
integrating we get
$$
Y_t = Y_0 + \beta\left(\mathrm{e}^{\alpha t} - 1\right) + \int_0^t\mathrm{e}^{\alpha s}dB_s
$$
or
$$
X_t = x_0 + \beta\left(1-\mathrm{e}^{-\alpha t}\right) + \int_0^t\mathrm{e}^{\alpha (s-t)}dB_s
$$

Comment: Thank you very much Chinny84. Does $X_t$ is a Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process? I have just found this on wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornstein%E2%80%93Uhlenbeck_process

Comment: Yes you are correct, but with volatility set to 1.